# I am trying to use Fitz to extract data from a pdf that contains text in a very unstructured format. But it's returning none at the first step

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, annotations, pymupdf

Here's the code I have been trying with the output:

```
import fitz
import pandas as pd 
doc = fitz.open('xyz.pdf')
page1 = doc[0]
words = page1.get_text("words")
```

first_annots=[]

rec=page1.first_annot.rect

rec

---

Output:
[image: output of above]

the output I am expecting is all text rectangles to be identified and called separately.
Here's where i found the code that i am implementing: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/data-extraction-from-unstructured-pdfs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent from your overall intention (to parse unstructured text):
Accessing the page's annotations via `page.first_annot` makes no sense at all.

Your exception is caused by the fact that that page page has no annotations, and therefore `page.first_annot` is `None` of course.

Again: whether or not there are annotations has nothing to do with the text of the page. Simply do not access `page.first_annot`.